# Cassandra Datastax Driver - Connection Pool

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to understand the connection pooling in Datastax Cassandra Driver, so I can better use it in my web service.

I have version 1.0 of the documentation. It says:

> The Java driver uses connections asynchronously, so multiple requests can be submitted on the same connection at the same time.

What do they understand by connection? When connecting to a cluster, we have: a Builder, a Cluster and a Session. Which one of them is the connection?

For example, there is this parameter:

> maxSimultaneousRequestsPerConnection - number of simultaneous requests on all connections
> to a host after which more connections are created.

So, these connections are automatically created, in the case of connection pooling (which is what I would expect). But what exactly are the connections? Cluster objects? Sessions?

I'm trying to decide what to keep 'static' in my web service. For the moment, I decided to keep the Builder static, so for every call I create a new Cluster and a new Session. Is this ok? If the Cluster is the Connection, then it should be ok. But is it? Now, the logger says, for every call:

> 2013:12:06 12:05:50 DEBUG Cluster:742 - Starting new cluster with contact points
>
> 2013:12:06 12:05:50 DEBUG ControlConnection:216 - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
>
> 2013:12:06 12:05:50 DEBUG ControlConnection:219 - [Control connection] Refreshing schema
>
> 2013:12:06 12:05:50 DEBUG ControlConnection:147 - [Control connection] Successfully connected to...

So, it connects to the Cluster every time? It's not what I want, I want to reuse connections.

So, the connection is actually the Session? If this is the case, I should keep the Cluster static, not the Builder.

What method should I call, to be sure I reuse connections, whenever possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, the connection is actually in the Session, and the Session is the object you should give to your DAOs to write into Cassandra.

As long as you use the same Session object, you should be reusing connections (you can see the Session as being your connection pool).

Edit (2017/4/10) : I precised this answer following @William Price one.
Please be aware that this answer is 4 years old, and Cassandra have changed a fair bit in the meantime !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, is the pooling logic kept in the Session, at query execution level? I would have expected it to be kept in the Cluster object, at session creation level.

Comment: The pooling policy is passed through the builder, and is used by the Session object to pick which node to query.

Comment: I'm just hoping that when multiple clients will use the same Session at the same time, they will actually use different physical connections.

Comment: @C4stor as @Anakin001 said `I'm just hoping that when multiple clients will use the same Session at the same time, they will actually use different physical connections. ` It it true

Comment: @PrakashPandey - actually, no.  In C* native protocol v2 and v3, the physical TCP connections are multiplexed. In these protocols, a _single TCP connection_ can support up to 128 and 32k+ simultaneous _in-flight_ asynchronous requests, respectively.

Answer (score 15):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423909/2390644) <sub><sub>(at the time of this writing)</sub></sub> is giving the correct advice:

> As long as you use the same Session object, you [will] be reusing connections.

However, some parts were originally oversimplified.  I hope the following provides insight into the scope of each object type and their respective purposes.

## Builder ≠ Cluster ≠ Session ≠ Connection ≠ Statement

#### A [`Cluster.Builder`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html) is used to configure and create a *Cluster*

#### A [`Cluster`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.html) represents the entire *Cassandra ring*

A ring consists of multiple nodes (hosts), and the ring can support one or more *keyspaces*.  You can query a *Cluster* object about cluster- (ring)-level properties.

I also think of it as the object that represents *the calling application* to the ring.  You communicated your application's needs (e.g. encryption, compression, etc.) to the builder, but it is *this object* that *first* implements/communicates with the actual C* ring.  If your application uses more than one *authentication credential* for different users/purposes, you likely have different *Cluster* objects even if they connect to the same ring.

#### A [`Session`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html) *itself is not* a connection, but it manages them

A session may need to talk to *all* nodes in the ring, which cannot be done with a single TCP connection except in the special case of rings that contain exactly one(1) node.  The *Session* manages a [*connection pool*](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/pooling/), and that pool will generally have at least one connection for *each node* in the ring.
**This is why you should re-use *Session* objects as much as possible. An application does not directly manage or access connections.**

A *Session* is accessed from the *Cluster* object; it is usually "bound" to a single *keyspace* at a time, which becomes the default keyspace for the *statements* executed from that session.  A statement can use a fully-qualified table name (e.g. `keyspacename.tablename`) to access tables in other keyspaces, so it's *not required* to use multiple sessions to access data across keyspaces.  Using multiple *sessions* to talk to the *same ring* increases the total number of TCP connections required.

#### A [`Statement`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html) executes within a *Session*

Statements can be [prepared](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#prepare-com.datastax.driver.core.RegularStatement-) or not, and each one either mutates data or queries it (and in some cases, both).  The fastest, most efficient statements need to communicate with at most one node, and a *Session* from a topology-aware *Cluster* should contact only that node (or one of its peers) on a single TCP connection.  The least efficient statements must touch all replicas (a majority of nodes), but that will be handled by the *coordinator node* on the ring itself, so even for these statements the *Session* will only use a single connection from the application.

Also, versions 2 and 3 of the Cassandra *binary protocol* used by the driver use *multiplexing* on the connections.  So while a single statement requires at least one TCP connection, that single connection can potentially service up to 128 or 32k+ asynchronous requests simultaneously, depending on the protocol version (respectively).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer (the currently accepted one) to at least reflect a bit your writing :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just an update for the community. You can set connection pool in the following way

```
private static Cluster cluster;

cluster.getConfiguration().getPoolingOptions().setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,100);
```